# How to build dynamically an array - add values in loop

Tags: php, string

A question from PHP self-learner.

My question is how can one dynamically build an array.

I have an array of some class values

```
$tags;
```

a class **tag** has a field called **Text**;

I need to build an array of strings populated from that field

NOTE for downvoters.
I am not PHP developer. I just need to do one simple task. I just do not know how to
dynamically build an array of strings. That is my question. Hope this question will help other people who are learning PHP.

Comment: So the class is named tag and it has a public var named $Text and for an array of instances of this class you need to grab the value of $Text and create an array of strings?

Comment: CRasco, yes. Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Tag {
    public $Text;
}

$tag1 = new Tag();
$tag2 = new Tag();
$tags = Array($tag1, $tag2);
```

Is that your problem? If so, keep in mind that PHP has loose data types so $Text could very well be a string. Try something like this:

```
$NewTags = Array();
foreach($Tags as $tag) {
    $NewTags[] = $tag->Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$textArray = array();

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    $textArray[] = $tag->Text;
}
```

This will take each tag object in the $tags array and add the Text value to an array called $textArray.

If this isn't what you were looking for, please let me know and I will do my best to adapt my answer.